Techniques used to study the structure of groups that are generated by sets that are too big
I have the following set: $M = \{\prod_{k=1}^n {(k,n+y_k)}\in S_{n+m}|(y_1,\dots,y_n) \in \{1,\dots,m\}^n\}$, where $n \geq 2, m \geq 2$ and $(k,n+y_k)$ denote transpositions in $S_{n+m}$. I've shown that $|M|=m^n$. Now I want to study another set that's basically obtained like this: $C = \{xmx|m \in M\}$. The problem is, $x$ is unknown and all there is, is a program that when given $m$ as input it gives $c = xmx$ as output. Obviously one can't recover $x$ except when $x$ is trivial which is omitted. It's clear that $|C| = |M|$. Now pick $\gamma = x\mu x$. For any $c = xmx$ the following holds $c\gamma^{-1} = xm \mu^{-1}x^{-1}$. Fix some $\gamma = x\mu x \in C$ and consider $C\gamma^{-1} = \{c\gamma^{-1} | c \in C\}$. It's easy to see that $\langle C\gamma^{-1} \rangle = x\langle M\mu^{-1} \rangle x^{-1}$. This makes it possible to study the relationship between $M$ and $C$ independently from $x$. To study $\langle C \gamma^{-1} \rangle$ means to study $C$ as well. The "only" problem is that $|C\gamma^{-1}|=m^n$. $n$ is usually going to be big enough that it would be impossible to go over every $\mu \in M$. What I'm wondering is if there are techniques to extract as much information as possible about $\langle C\gamma^{-1}\rangle$ by not having the possibility to go through every element of $C\gamma^{-1}$. For example, it's known that there can be found a "handful" of permutations in $\langle C\gamma^{-1} \rangle$ that will generate the entire group, but finding all of them is again practically impossible. Are there any techniques that can be applied in such situations?
P.S. basically $C$ is the set of ciphers and $M$ the set of messages and I'm trying to see if there are algebraic relationships that involve large classes of elements in $C$.

Your set builder notation is confusing. What is $y_k$? On the left of the $|$ the symbol $y_k$ seems to be a fixed number for each $k=1,...,n$. But on the right of the $|$ the symbol $y_k$ seems to be a variable ranging in values from $1$ to $m$.

Perhaps your intention is that $y \in {1,\ldots,m}^n$ instead of $y_k=1,\ldots,m$?

@LeeMosher yes! I'll edit for clarity
